# Error during use $within operator with $elemMatch

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using spring-data-mongodb (version 1.0.2.RELEASE) and mongodb (version 2.2).
I have an object A that contain a list of object Location. The classes are the following:

```
public class A {

@Id
private ObjectId id;

private List<Location> places;

//GETTER AND SETTER
}



public class Place {

private String name;

private String description;

@GeoSpatialIndexed
private double[] location;

//GETTER AND SETTER
}
```

I need to find all objects A with a specific location. 
I tried to use together the operators $within and $elemMatch as following:

```
@Query(value = "{'places' : { $elemMatch: { location: {'$within' : {'$center' : [?0, ?1]} } }}}")
public List<A> findByLocation(Point location, double radius);
```

When i run this query, i receive the following exception:

> org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: can't find special index: 2d for: { places: { $elemMatch: { location: { $within: { $center: [ { x: 41.904159, y: 12.549132 }, 0.07000000000000001 ] } } } } }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: can't find special index: 2d for: { places: { $elemMatch: { location: { $within: { $center: [ { x: 41.904159, y: 12.549132 }, 0.07000000000000001 ] } } } } }

Any suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem changing A class. I replaced the list of Place with a list of org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.Point as follow:

```
public class A {

@Id
private ObjectId id;

@GeoSpatialIndexed
private List<Point> places;

//GETTER AND SETTER
}
```

And i replaced old query with a new one as follow:

```
@Query(value = "{'places' : {'$within' : {'$center' : [?0, ?1]} } }")
public List<A> findByLocation(Point location, double radius);
```

And now it's work!

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's no 2d index on the `location` attribute, and MongoDB requires such an index to be present. I don't know if Spring should be creating that index by itself, but if it doesn't, you can create the index via

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"location":"2d"})
```

where `collection` is replaced by the name of your collection.

Comment: Anyway i executed 'db.collection.getIndexes()' command and i saw that 2d index on field 'places.location' already exist